# In Angular 4, can I programmatically change the type of component being used in a template?

Tags: html, angular2-template

I have a component (let's call it ListComponent) whose purpose is to edit a list. It allows the user to add, delete, and reorder elements. Its template looks something like this:

```
<div> <!-- Some Buttons --> </div>
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="element in dataArray">
        <string-editor [(NgModel)]=element></string-editor>
        <!-- More Buttons -->
    </li>
</ul>
```

The `<string-editor>` is also a custom component with a template that is basically just an input component with a bit of styling. What I want to be able to do is have multiple versions of ListComponent that can handle different types of data (e.g. numbers, custom objects with multiple fields.) To do this, I would like to be able to replace `<string-editor>` in the template with another component class (like `<number-editor>` or `<my-custom-object-editor>`.) They would all support NgModel. I have looked into dynamic component creation, but it appears that there is no way I can use it with `*ngFor`'s change detection.

So, in summary, is there a way to change `<string-editor>` to another tag programmatically? If not, is there a way that I can use dynamic component creation with `*ngFor`'s change detection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is.

Use a ng switch if u can determine what type of component you need to use. Or You can also write a Ng if else

NgSwitch  https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitch
ng if else https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf

Comment: I will use that as a workaround for now. The way the website is shaping up, I will need lists of several types of custom objects. I would prefer a solution where I can specify the component to be used instead of `<string-editor>` when it is needed (e.g. through a method, subclass, etc.) rather than having to hard-code for all possible object types in the template.

Comment: I dont know if the code for this in ngFor is possible but you can also explore this  https://netbasal.com/angular-2-understanding-viewcontainerref-acc183f3b682

Comment: I will look into that and post back whether or not it works. It looks somewhat promising.

Comment: Unfortunately, I could not get it to work for my use case. I will continue with the ngIf solution for now.